# Question about Rails Dispatch article screencasts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is programming related, even if not directly. The articles from Rails Dispatch make references to screencasts, but I cannot find them. For example, [this article](http://railsdispatch.com/posts/rails-routing) talks about a screencast too, but I cannot find it. Do you know how they can be accessed?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to find?

Comment: As he said in his question, he wants to know how to access the screencast mentioned in the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching I think I have found them. Head over to http://www.engineyard.com/videos and there are a bunch of Rails Dispatch screencasts there. They should ideally actually link them in the article mentioned though.

I could not load the video since I am at work and bandwidth is precious around here but I think the specific screencast is this one => http://www.engineyard.com/v/11705239

Comment: Thank you. I also posted a suggestion on their website to provide links to the videos.

Comment: well I need to thank you, because prior to your question I had not really heard of RailsDispatch :) now I have :D

Comment: Maybe you'd be interested in http://rubytu.be/ as well? That's where I found the links to Rails Dispatch.